# Mainframe ICETOOL joins two files

Tags: mainframe

I have two VB files.

File1 is 406 bytes long, and the key is in position 401 to 406.

File2 is 565 bytes long, and the key is in position 87 to 92.

I would like the result file to have all the 406 bytes from file1 plus 8 bytes from file2 starts from column 42.

I have the following codes:

```
//COPY01   EXEC PGM=ICETOOL
//TOOLMSG  DD SYSOUT=*
//DFSMSG   DD SYSOUT=*
//IN01     DD DSN=CCSY.CCSYAC.BNS.C2,DISP=SHR
//IN02     DD DSN=CCSY.CCSYAC.UID.XBAS,DISP=SHR
//OUT01    DD DSN=CCSY.CCSYAC.BNS.C2.ID,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=410,BLKSIZE=41000),
//            SPACE=(CYL,(200,100),RLSE)
//TOOLIN   DD *
  COPY JKFROM TO(OUT01) VSAMTYPE(V) USING(BNSC)
/*
//BNSCCNTL DD *
  JOINKEYS F1=IN01,FIELDS=(401,6,A)
  JOINKEYS F2=IN02,FIELDS=(87,6,A)
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:5,402,F2:42,8)
/*
```

I got S013. Anyone would like to help? I'll appreciate.

JESMSGLG:

```
13.02.33 JOB38364 ---- WEDNESDAY, 10 JAN 2018 ----
13.02.33 JOB38364  IRR010I  USERID CCSYAC   IS ASSIGNED TO THIS JOB.
13.02.34 JOB38364  ICH70001I CCSYAC   LAST ACCESS AT 12:56:19 ON WEDNESDAY, JANUARY 10, 2018
13.02.34 JOB38364  $HASP373 CCSYAC02 STARTED - INIT 68   - CLASS J        - SYS SY07
13.02.34 JOB38364  IEF403I CCSYAC02 - STARTED - TIME=13.02.34
13.02.35 JOB38364  IEC141I 013-68,IFG0196L,CCSYAC02,COPY01,OUT01,B275,STRP49,  005
   005             CCSY.CCSYAC.BNS.C2.ID
13.02.35 JOB38364  IEA995I SYMPTOM DUMP OUTPUT  006
   006             SYSTEM COMPLETION CODE=013  REASON CODE=00000068
   006              TIME=13.02.35  SEQ=61720  CPU=0000  ASID=0058
   006              PSW AT TIME OF ERROR  075C1000   80E70476  ILC 2  INTC 0D
   006                NO ACTIVE MODULE FOUND
   006                NAME=UNKNOWN
   006                DATA AT PSW  00E70470 - 4100302C  0A0D010D  A7E5014B
   006                AR/GR 0: 008FE990/00E70780   1: 00000000/A4013000         
   006                      2: 00000000/0000DCC8   3: 00000000/00E70754
   006                      4: 00000000/008C4388   5: 00000000/008C471C
   006                      6: 00000000/008C46C4   7: 00000000/008C471C
   006                      8: 00000000/008C46E4   9: 00000000/008D1C50
   006                      A: 00000000/80E72A62   B: 00000000/00E73622
   006                      C: 00000000/80E7387E   D: 00000000/7F59FCE8
   006                      E: 00000000/80E6FCD4   F: 00000000/00000068
   006              END OF SYMPTOM DUMP
13.02.47 JOB38364  IEF450I CCSYAC02 COPY01 - ABEND=S013 U0000 REASON=00000068  011
   011                     TIME=13.02.47
13.02.47 JOB38364  IEF404I CCSYAC02 - ENDED - TIME=13.02.47
13.02.47 JOB38364  $HASP395 CCSYAC02 ENDED - ABEND=S013
------ JES2 JOB STATISTICS ------
  10 JAN 2018 JOB EXECUTION DATE
           26 CARDS READ
          563 SYSOUT PRINT RECORDS
            0 SYSOUT PUNCH RECORDS
           54 SYSOUT SPOOL KBYTES
         0.22 MINUTES EXECUTION TIME
```

TOOLMSG:

```
ICE600I 0 DFSORT ICETOOL UTILITY RUN STARTED

ICE650I 0 VISIT http://www.ibm.com/storage/dfsort FOR ICETOOL PAPERS, 
EXAMPLES AND MORE

ICE632I 0 SOURCE FOR ICETOOL STATEMENTS:  TOOLIN


ICE630I 0 MODE IN EFFECT:  STOP

            COPY JKFROM TO(OUT01) VSAMTYPE(V) USING(BNSC)
```

DFSMSG:

```
ICE200I 0 IDENTIFIER FROM CALLING PROGRAM IS 0001
ICE411I 0 THIS IS THE JOINKEYS MAIN TASK FOR JOINING F1 AND F2
ICE416I 0 JOINKEYS IS USING THE F1 SUBTASK FOR IN01     - SEE JNF1JMSG MESSAGES
ICE416I 1 JOINKEYS IS USING THE F2 SUBTASK FOR IN02     - SEE JNF2JMSG MESSAGES
ICE419I 0 JOINED RECORDS: TYPE=F, LENGTH=410
ICE201I A RECORD TYPE IS F - DATA STARTS IN POSITION 1
ICE751I 0 C5-I40658 C6-I35397 C7-I35397 C8-I40658 E9-I40658 C9-I35397 E5-
I38877 E7-I40658
ICE143I 0 BLOCKSET     COPY  TECHNIQUE SELECTED
ICE250I 0 VISIT http://www.ibm.com/storage/dfsort FOR DFSORT PAPERS, EXAMPLES AND MORE
ICE000I 0 - CONTROL STATEMENTS FOR 5650-ZOS, Z/OS DFSORT V2R2  - 13:02 ON WED JAN 10, 2018 -
            JOINKEYS F1=IN01,FIELDS=(401,6,A)
            JOINKEYS F2=IN02,FIELDS=(87,6,A)
            REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:5,402,F2:42,8)
ICE146I 0 END OF STATEMENTS FROM BNSCCNTL - PARAMETER LIST STATEMENTS FOLLOW
      DEBUG NOABEND,ESTAE
      OPTION MSGDDN=DFSMSG,LIST,MSGPRT=ALL,RESINV=0,SORTDD=BNSC,SORTOUT=OUT01*
                         ,DYNALLOC
          SORT FIELDS=COPY    
          RECORD TYPE=V
ICE193I 0 ICEAM2 INVOCATION ENVIRONMENT IN EFFECT - ICEAM2 ENVIRONMENT SELECTED
ICE089I 0 CCSYAC02.COPY01  .        , INPUT LRECL = 410, TYPE = F
ICE093I 0 MAIN STORAGE = (MAX,6291456,6291456)
ICE156I 0 MAIN STORAGE ABOVE 16MB = (6234096,6234096)
ICE127I 0 OPTIONS: OVFLO=RC0 ,PAD=RC0 ,TRUNC=RC0 ,SPANINC=RC16,VLSCMP=N,SZERO=Y,RESET=Y,VSAMEMT=Y,DYNSPC=256
ICE128I 0 OPTIONS: SIZE=6291456,MAXLIM=1024000,MINLIM=122800,EQUALS=N,LIST=Y,ERET=RC16 ,MSGDDN=DFSMSG
ICE129I 0 OPTIONS: VIO=N,RESDNT=ALL ,SMF=NO   ,WRKSEC=Y,OUTSEC=Y,VERIFY=N,CHALT=N,DYNALOC=N             ,ABCODE=MSG
ICE130I 0 OPTIONS: RESALL=4096,RESINV=0,SVC=109 ,CHECK=N,WRKREL=Y,OUTREL=Y,CKPT=N,COBEXIT=COB2
ICE131I 0 OPTIONS: TMAXLIM=6291456,ARESALL=0,ARESINV=0,OVERRGN=16384,CINV=Y,CFW=Y,DSA=0
ICE132I 0 OPTIONS: VLSHRT=N,ZDPRINT=Y,IEXIT=N,TEXIT=N,LISTX=N,EFS=NONE    ,EXITCK=S,PARMDDN=DFSPARM ,FSZEST=N
ICE133I 0 OPTIONS: HIPRMAX=OPTIMAL,DSPSIZE=MAX ,ODMAXBF=0,SOLRF=Y,VLLONG=N,VSAMIO=N,MOSIZE=MAX
ICE235I 0 OPTIONS: NULLOUT=RC0
ICE236I 0 OPTIONS: DYNAPCT=10 ,MOWRK=Y,TUNE=STOR,EXPMAX=MAX    ,EXPOLD=50%    ,EXPRES=10%
ICE084I 0 EXCP ACCESS METHOD USED FOR OUT01
ICE751I 2 EF-I35397 DA-I40658
ICE805I 0 JOBNAME: CCSYAC02 , STEPNAME: COPY01
ICE802I 0 BLOCKSET     TECHNIQUE IN CONTROL
ICE906I 0 ST=ABOVE,SR=6291456,RC=0
ICE907I 0 ST=ABOVE,SA=6291440,NF=1,LF=6291440,SF=6291440
ICE906I 0 ST=BELOW,SR=1036288,RC=0
ICE907I 0 ST=BELOW,SA=1036272,NF=1,LF=1036272,SF=1036272
ICE889I 0 CT=MAX     , SB=8, L=0, D=0000, CCW=1MAM
ICE902I 0 O RP10  I  
ICE906I 1 ST=ABOVE,SR=6234096,RC=0
ICE907I 1 ST=ABOVE,SA=6234080,NF=1,LF=6234080,SF=6234080
ICE906I 1 ST=BELOW,SR=94680,RC=0
ICE907I 1 ST=BELOW,SA=49608,NF=1,LF=49608,SF=49608
ICE185A 0 AN S013  ABEND WAS ISSUED BY DFSORT, ANOTHER PROGRAM OR AN EXIT (PHASE C 3)
```

JNF1JMSG:

```
ICE201I A RECORD TYPE IS V - DATA STARTS IN POSITION 5
ICE751I 0 C5-I40658 C6-I35397 C7-I35397 C8-I40658 E4-I40658 C9-I35397 E5-
I38877 E6-I31999 C4-I31999 E7-I40658
ICE417I 0 THIS IS THE JOINKEYS F1 SUBTASK FOR IN01
ICE143I 0 BLOCKSET     SORT  TECHNIQUE SELECTED
ICE250I 0 VISIT http://www.ibm.com/storage/dfsort FOR DFSORT PAPERS, EXAMPLES AND MORE
ICE000I 0 - CONTROL STATEMENTS FOR 5650-ZOS, Z/OS DFSORT V2R2  - 13:02 ON WED JAN 10, 2018 -
          SORT  FORMAT=BI,FIELDS=(401,6,A)
          RECORD TYPE=F
          DEBUG NOABEND,ESTAE
          OPTION EQUALS,MSGPRT=ALL,LIST,NOCHECK,RESINV=0,DYNALLOC,SORTDD=JNF1,MSG*
                         DDN=JNF1JMSG,SORTIN=IN01
ICE193I 0 ICEAM2 INVOCATION ENVIRONMENT IN EFFECT - ICEAM2 ENVIRONMENT SELECTED
ICE088I 0 CCSYAC02.COPY01  .        , INPUT LRECL = 406, BLKSIZE = 27998, TYPE = VB
ICE093I 0 MAIN STORAGE = (MAX,9251025,9251025)     
ICE156I 0 MAIN STORAGE ABOVE 16MB = (9193665,9193665)
ICE127I 0 OPTIONS: OVFLO=RC0 ,PAD=RC0 ,TRUNC=RC0 ,SPANINC=RC16,VLSCMP=N,SZERO=Y,,RESET=Y,VSAMEMT=Y,DYNSPC=256
ICE128I 0 OPTIONS: SIZE=9251025,MAXLIM=1024000,MINLIM=122800,EQUALS=Y,LIST=Y,ERET=RC16 ,MSGDDN=JNF1JMSG
ICE129I 0 OPTIONS: VIO=N,RESDNT=ALL ,SMF=NO   ,WRKSEC=Y,OUTSEC=Y,VERIFY=N,CHALT==N,DYNALOC=(DISK    ,004),ABCODE=MSG
ICE130I 0 OPTIONS: RESALL=4096,RESINV=0,SVC=109 ,CHECK=N,WRKREL=Y,OUTREL=Y,CKPT=N,COBEXIT=COB2
ICE131I 0 OPTIONS: TMAXLIM=6291456,ARESALL=0,ARESINV=0,OVERRGN=16384,CINV=Y,CFW=Y,DSA=128
ICE132I 0 OPTIONS: VLSHRT=N,ZDPRINT=Y,IEXIT=N,TEXIT=N,LISTX=N,EFS=NONE    ,EXITCK=S,PARMDDN=DFSPARM ,FSZEST=N
ICE133I 0 OPTIONS: HIPRMAX=OPTIMAL,DSPSIZE=MAX ,ODMAXBF=0,SOLRF=Y,VLLONG=N,VSAMIIO=N,MOSIZE=MAX
ICE235I 0 OPTIONS: NULLOUT=RC0
ICE236I 0 OPTIONS: DYNAPCT=10 ,MOWRK=Y,TUNE=STOR,EXPMAX=MAX    ,EXPOLD=50%    ,EXPRES=10%
ICE084I 0 EXCP ACCESS METHOD USED FOR IN01
ICE750I 0 DC 589973550 TC 0 CS DSVXX KSZ 10 VSZ 10
ICE752I 0 FSZ=589973550 BC  IGN=0 E  AVG=203 0  WSP=766274 C  DYN=520 53216
ICE751I 1 D8-I35397 D4-I35397 EA-I35933 F1-I35933 E8-I40658
ICE091I 0 OUTPUT LRECL = 406, TYPE = V
ICE055I 0 INSERT 0, DELETE 0
ICE054I 0 RECORDS - IN: 1433042, OUT: 0
ICE134I 0 NUMBER OF BYTES SORTED: 581815052
ICE253I 0 RECORDS SORTED - PROCESSED: 1433042, EXPECTED: 2906273
ICE098I 0 AVERAGE RECORD LENGTH - PROCESSED: 406, EXPECTED: 203
ICE165I 0 TOTAL WORK DATA SET TRACKS ALLOCATED: 540 , TRACKS USED: 0
ICE199I 0 MEMORY OBJECT USED AS MAIN STORAGE = 0M BYTES
ICE299I 0 MEMORY OBJECT USED AS WORK STORAGE = 563M BYTES
ICE180I 0 HIPERSPACE STORAGE USED = 0K BYTES
ICE188I 0 DATA SPACE STORAGE USED = 0K BYTES
ICE052I 0 END OF DFSORT
```

JNF2JMSG:

```
ICE201I A RECORD TYPE IS V - DATA STARTS IN POSITION 5
ICE751I 0 C5-I40658 C6-I35397 C7-I35397 C8-I40658 E4-I40658 C9-I35397 E5-
I38877 E6-I31999 E7-I40658
ICE417I 0 THIS IS THE JOINKEYS F2 SUBTASK FOR IN02
ICE143I 0 BLOCKSET     SORT  TECHNIQUE SELECTED
ICE250I 0 VISIT http://www.ibm.com/storage/dfsort FOR DFSORT PAPERS, EXAMPLES AND MORE
ICE000I 0 - CONTROL STATEMENTS FOR 5650-ZOS, Z/OS DFSORT V2R2  - 13:02 ON WED JAN 10, 2018 -
          SORT  FORMAT=BI,FIELDS=(87,6,A)
          RECORD TYPE=F         
          DEBUG NOABEND,ESTAE
          OPTION EQUALS,MSGPRT=ALL,LIST,NOCHECK,RESINV=0,DYNALLOC,SORTDD=JNF2,MSG*
                         DDN=JNF2JMSG,SORTIN=IN02
ICE193I 0 ICEAM2 INVOCATION ENVIRONMENT IN EFFECT - ICEAM2 ENVIRONMENT SELECTED
ICE088I 0 CCSYAC02.COPY01  .        , INPUT LRECL = 565, BLKSIZE = 27998, TYPE = VB
ICE093I 0 MAIN STORAGE = (MAX,6291456,6291456)
ICE156I 0 MAIN STORAGE ABOVE 16MB = (6234096,6234096)
ICE127I 0 OPTIONS: OVFLO=RC0 ,PAD=RC0 ,TRUNC=RC0 ,SPANINC=RC16,VLSCMP=N,SZERO=Y,RESET=Y,VSAMEMT=Y,DYNSPC=256
ICE128I 0 OPTIONS: SIZE=6291456,MAXLIM=1024000,MINLIM=122800,EQUALS=Y,LIST=Y,ERET=RC16 ,MSGDDN=JNF2JMSG
ICE129I 0 OPTIONS: VIO=N,RESDNT=ALL ,SMF=NO   ,WRKSEC=Y,OUTSEC=Y,VERIFY=N,CHALT=N,DYNALOC=(DISK    ,004),ABCODE=MSG
ICE130I 0 OPTIONS: RESALL=4096,RESINV=0,SVC=109 ,CHECK=N,WRKREL=Y,OUTREL=Y,CKPT=N,COBEXIT=COB2
ICE131I 0 OPTIONS: TMAXLIM=6291456,ARESALL=0,ARESINV=0,OVERRGN=16384,CINV=Y,CFW=Y,DSA=0
ICE132I 0 OPTIONS: VLSHRT=N,ZDPRINT=Y,IEXIT=N,TEXIT=N,LISTX=N,EFS=NONE    ,EXITCK=S,PARMDDN=DFSPARM ,FSZEST=N
ICE133I 0 OPTIONS: HIPRMAX=OPTIMAL,DSPSIZE=MAX ,ODMAXBF=0,SOLRF=Y,VLLONG=N,VSAMIO=N,MOSIZE=MAX
ICE235I 0 OPTIONS: NULLOUT=RC0
ICE236I 0 OPTIONS: DYNAPCT=10 ,MOWRK=Y,TUNE=STOR,EXPMAX=MAX    ,EXPOLD=50%    ,EXPRES=10%
ICE084I 0 EXCP ACCESS METHOD USED FOR IN02
ICE750I 0 DC 1063772 TC 0 CS DSVXX KSZ 10 VSZ 10
ICE752I 0 FSZ=1063772 BC  IGN=0 E  AVG=282 0  WSP=1381 C  DYN=0 0
ICE751I 1 D8-I35397 D4-I35397 D1-I35397 E8-I40658
ICE091I 0 OUTPUT LRECL = 565, TYPE = V
ICE080I 0 IN MAIN STORAGE SORT
ICE055I 0 INSERT 0, DELETE 0
ICE054I 0 RECORDS - IN: 3603, OUT: 0
ICE134I 0 NUMBER OF BYTES SORTED: 1034061
ICE253I 0 RECORDS SORTED - PROCESSED: 3603, EXPECTED: 3772
ICE098I 0 AVERAGE RECORD LENGTH - PROCESSED: 287, EXPECTED: 282
ICE165I 0 TOTAL WORK DATA SET TRACKS ALLOCATED: 0 , TRACKS USED: 0
ICE199I 0 MEMORY OBJECT USED AS MAIN STORAGE = 0M BYTES
ICE299I 0 MEMORY OBJECT USED AS WORK STORAGE = 0M BYTES
ICE180I 0 HIPERSPACE STORAGE USED = 0K BYTES  
ICE188I 0 DATA SPACE STORAGE USED = 0K BYTES
ICE052I 0 END OF DFSORT
```

Comment: The JESMSGLG for your job should have the complete message associated with the S013, please edit your question and add that information.

Comment: AS cschneid said: with an S013 there should be an IEC141I message that explains what went wrong.

Comment: JESMSGLG added.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the description for the S013 error you encountered:

> The SORTIN, SORTOUT, or OUTFIL BLKSIZE     parameter:
>
> Was greater than 32760 for a disk data    set, or was greater than the maximum block size
>   supported by the access method for a  tape data set.
>
> Was not an integer multiple of the LRECL  parameter for fixed-length records, or was not
>   at least four bytes longer than the    LRECL for variable-length
>   records.

and if you look at the JCL you provided:

```
//COPY01   EXEC PGM=ICETOOL
//TOOLMSG  DD SYSOUT=*
//DFSMSG   DD SYSOUT=*
//IN01     DD DSN=CCSY.CCSYAC.BNS.C2,DISP=SHR
//IN02     DD DSN=CCSY.CCSYAC.UID.XBAS,DISP=SHR
//OUT01    DD DSN=CCSY.CCSYAC.BNS.C2.ID,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=410,BLKSIZE=41000),
//            SPACE=(CYL,(200,100),RLSE)
//TOOLIN   DD *
  COPY JKFROM TO(OUT01) VSAMTYPE(V) USING(BNSC)
/*
//BNSCCNTL DD *
  JOINKEYS F1=IN01,FIELDS=(401,6,A)
  JOINKEYS F2=IN02,FIELDS=(87,6,A)
  REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:5,402,F2:42,8)
/*
```

You can see that your block size of 41000 is greater than that 32760 maximum. Try not specifying the block size. If you do not specify the block size in the JCL, the system will calculate an efficient one for you.

Comment: Current releases of z/OS will calculate the most efficient block size for you if you refrain from specifying it in your JCL.  Absent that, I would suggest a block size of 27880 as it is likely to perform better.  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idad500/tcd.htm.

Comment: good idea, ill edit my answer to say not to include the block size and let the system calculate it